# Trying to make a simple jumping script in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Recently started trying to learn pygame with the goal of making a simple platformer. So far, I've created a player that can move left and right and is affected by gravity. I haven't yet implemented object collision. Right now I'm trying to make a simple jump script. My current script for vertical movement is the following:

```
if man.y + man.height < ground:
    man.yvel += man.velInc
elif man.y + man.height >= ground:
    if man.isJump == True:
        man.isJump == False
    man.yvel = 0
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and man.isJump == False:
    man.yvel = -20
    man.isJump = True
man.y += man.yvel
```

This is run in a loop along with other stuff such as horizontal movement. `ground` is a variable that determines the y-coordinate of the ground, and is currently set to 350. The height of the window is 450. `man.velInc` is set to 1 and `man.height` is set to 32 I can provide any other info if necessary.

My problem is that when I run the program, I can only jump once, and then never again. I can still move left and right normally. I put in a script to print out `man.x`, `man.y`, and `man.isJump`. Before the jump, `man.isJump` is "False", and after, `True`. It never goes back to False. `man.y` also reads as 328. The jump itself however seems to work perfectly. I would appreciate any help to fix the issue, and maybe some advice on how to avoid things like this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the `==` (Boolean equality) with `=` (set variable)

```
if man.y + man.height < ground:
    man.yvel += man.velInc
elif man.y + man.height >= ground:
    if man.isJump == True:
        man.isJump = False # replace == with =
    man.yvel = 0
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and man.isJump == False:
    man.yvel = -20
    man.isJump = True
man.y += man.yvel
```

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.